# AWS EC2 CloudWatch Mem Util and Disk Util in AutoScaleGroup

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, cloudwatch

Recently, I've been investigating how to setup CloudWatch Monitoring in our AWS instances to include Mem Util and Disk Util.

I've followed [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html).
It worked like a charm.

I have everything working on our Production-REF (Reference) box.  I create an Image, and add it to our Launch Configuration for our AutoScaleGroup.  Everything deploys fine, and all the scripts run.

**The Problem**:
The instance-id is cached on the AutoScale boxes, so it sends all information back as the Production-REF box.

I don't really want to tweak the out of the box AWS script, but I see in CloudWatchClient.pm it calls get_instance_id, which calls get_meta_data, which uses cache [ http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data ].

Anyway to clear http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data cache?  Preferably just the first time its called on that instance.  Maybe another way?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That value should not be cached. It should be unique for every instance. Its not provided by the image, instead its generated by the hypervisor control system.

Answer (score 3):

I found the cached file:
`/var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id`

If you remove that, it'll auto replace it with the correct (AutoScaled Box's Instance Id).